# Address range of processer

Tags: assembly, x86

I am new to assembly Language, I find this question on the internet but i was not able to answer it, Can any one please help me solve this question.

```
What is the address range of a processor having 
(a) 40 address lines 
(b) 34 address lines
```

Comment: Who said the learning should be easy? It is a hard work and only the most persistent should survive. ;)

Comment: @AniqMakhani: Questions to StackOverflow tend to be about answers to problems. What is your difficulty with trying to find a solution to this homework problem? What have you tried, and why doesn't it work or where do you think you may be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Each address line is one digit in a base 2 system, so figure out what the largest number is that can be represented by the number of address lines in a base 2 system.

**Example:**  In a decimal (base 10) system, the number of possible numbers that can be represented in a three-digit system is 10 to the third power, or 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Each address line can be a "high" voltage or "low" voltage (alternatively "0" or "1").

So each line has two possible states.

So one address line can only address 2 addresses -- `0` (line low) or `1` (line high).  These correspond to decimal addresses 0 and 1 (converting binary to decimal).

Two address lines can address 4 addresses -- `00` (both lines low), `01` (first line low, second high), `10` (first high, second low), `11` (both lines high).  These correspond to decimal addresses 0, 1, 2, and 3.

Three address lines can address 8 addresses -- `000` (all lines low), `001` (only third line high), `010` (only second line high), `011` (only first line low), `100` (only first line high), `101` (only second line low), `110` (only third line low), `111` (all lines high), corresponding to decimal addresses 0-7.

And so on.

Hopefully you can see the pattern here: 2, 4, 8, 16, ...

Comment: I got it, the pattern would 2 power n which means the answer would be 2^40. Am i right?